# Variable from other class doesn't get value in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe

I'm experiencing a very basic trouble in Java which blocks me from implementing and testing a project. The problem is that while I'm using an MVC pattern once a button is pressed I need to open a new JFrame where I draw N red rectangles. According to the MVC pattern the input value N is read from a text field in the Control class, where I tested and reads the value correctly. However, when I get into the new frame the value disappears and I get a nullPointerException.

I also tried similar question's source codes from here (like this: [Using paintComponent() to draw rectangle in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404398/using-paintcomponent-to-draw-rectangle-in-jframe)), but none of them seemed to work.

Relevant part of the Control class is:

```
private void readInput()
{
    numberOfQueues = Integer.parseInt(v_view.field1.getText());
}
public int getNumberOfQueues()
{
    return numberOfQueues;
}
class StartListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(m_model.validateInput(v_view.field1.getText()) && m_model.validateInput(v_view.field2.getText()) &&
                   m_model.validateInput(v_view.field3.getText()) && m_model.validateInput(v_view.field4.getText()) && 
                   m_model.validateInput(v_view.field5.getText()) && m_model.validateInput(v_view.field6.getText()))
                {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(v_view.field3.getText()) <= Integer.parseInt(v_view.field4.getText()) &&
                        Integer.parseInt(v_view.field5.getText()) <= Integer.parseInt(v_view.field6.getText()))
                    {
                        readInput();
                        SimulationFrame simulationFrame = new SimulationFrame(m_model);
                        simulationFrame.setVisible(true);
                        simulationFrame.repaint();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input range! Please try again!");
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Input validation is surely good and if I try here to print out the value of numberOfQueues does it well.

The class which extends the JFrame looks the following:

```
public class SimulationFrame extends JFrame{

Control control;
private int numberOfQueues;

public SimulationFrame(Model model)
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 550));
    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("Simulator Frame");
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    numberOfQueues=control.getNumberOfQueues();
    System.out.println(numberOfQueues);
    repaint();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfQueues; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(control.numberOfQueues);
        g.fill3DRect(50+20, 20, 50, 50, true);
    }

}
```

I also tried to call the repaint method in both places, I also tried not using a getter, just getting the value directly through a class instance, I also tried inside the constructor, outside the constructor, wherever it could be positioned, but somewhere I keep making the same obvious mistake which I couldn't find.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your View the model class (which should have how many rectangles you want to draw) but you are calling "control.getNumberOfQueues()" which you never instantiate "Control control"

Your view should not know about the control, it should render your model using the model you passed it. Your control should take input and update the model with the number of rectangles and then your view should render that model again.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I made a total mess out of my view class. This way you said works. Thanks for the help!